# How to Use Color Thief With UWP

Tags: c#, colors, uwp, color-thief

I loading images source from internet and I need this images dominant color. Forexample [this](https://yt3.ggpht.com/-cYK4gMKhvV0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/8znlvBw-Wos/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg) image and then found color thief but I cant understand.

I using this method but I think it's wrong.

```
BitmapDecoder BMD = new BitmapDecoder("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-cYK4gMKhvV0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/8znlvBw-Wos/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg");
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
await colorThief.GetColor(BMD);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right that the `GetColor` method of [ColorThief](https://github.com/KSemenenko/ColorThief) requires a [`BitmapDecoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder) parameter. But `BitmapDecode` is not created by the way you are trying.  `BitmapDecoder` can be created by [`IRandomAccessStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream)  according to [`CreateAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder#Windows_Graphics_Imaging_BitmapDecoder_CreateAsync_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_) method, cannot be created directly by a Uri. So you need a `RandomAccessStream` object firstly. This can be done by creating a `RandomAccessStreamReference` by [`RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(Uri)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.randomaccessstreamreference#Windows_Storage_Streams_RandomAccessStreamReference_CreateFromUri_Windows_Foundation_Uri_), and then open and read it. A complete demo by using the ColorThief is as follows you can reference:

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-cYK4gMKhvV0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/8znlvBw-Wos/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg");
RandomAccessStreamReference random = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(imageUri);
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await random.OpenReadAsync())   
{
    //Create a decoder for the image
    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = await colorThief.GetColor(decoder);       
}
```